# How to select this container element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I having trouble to select the currently clicked container element.

My Html

```
<div class="cparent">
foo1
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>

<div class="cparent">
foo2
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
```

I mean when I click on delete link, corresponding container should disappear. How can I do this?

What I tried !

```
$(".cparent",this).html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();// not working
```

My script

```
$(".delete").live("click",function(){
 var cur = $(".delete").index(this);
 $(".cparent").eq(cur).html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
 });
```

Above one is also not working. Have a look at [this Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/YFMZW/1/) for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `parent`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/parent)]</sup>* method:

```
$(this).parent().html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

Passing `this` as the second parameter to the jQuery function won't find elements that are above `this`. Alternatively, you can use the `closest`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/closest)]</sup>* method:

```
$(this).closest('.cparent').html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Suppose i am having additional div around "Delete".for example   **<div class="cparent">
foo1<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete">Delete</a></div>
</div>**

Comment: Which one would you want to delete in this case?

Comment: If you wrapped the `<a>` in another `<div>`, then used want to go with the alternative method that uses the `closest` method. Example above.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo:Thank you so much.+1 for closet. That's what i am exactly looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use `closest` to select the immediate parent

```
$(".delete").live("click",function(){
 var cur = $(this);
 cur.closest("div.cparent").html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
 });
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/10/**

[**`jquery closest`**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.cparent').click (function (e)
{
    if ($(e.target).attr ('class') == 'delete')
    {
        $(this).html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
    }
}
);
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/usPQb/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/):

```
$(this).parent().html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/YFMZW/1/

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using seems to be a bit more complex than it needs to.

Try using this as your handler, it is more precise and easier to read:

`$(this).parent(".cparent").html('Deleting...').delay(1000).fadeOut();`