# getting container element with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

I'm using an asp.net repeater control to output the following markup:

```
<div class="detailsItem">
    <table style="width:100%;border: solid green 1px">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
            <a href="javascript:editItem($(this).closest('.detailsitem'));">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I thought the code `$(this).closest('.detailsitem')` would give me the containing div. If I do an alert on what's passed to editItem, I just get some javascript code showing up. Not sure where that comes from. I've tried various combinations of `.parent` etc with no luck.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111642/how-to-select-this-container-element-in-jquery) which is similar, but it didn't seem to help me out. I'm assuming the problem might be with my function call.

What am I missing?

many thanks, as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a class for your anchors in the repeater

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit">Edit</a>
```

In `ready` event, attach a click event handler for all your Anchor's:

```
$(".edit").live("click",function(){
    var cur = $(this);
    editItem(cur.closest("div.detailsItem"));
 });
```

Comment: brilliant. SO to the rescue again!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors are case sensitive try the following... (uppercase I in items)

```
$(this).closest('.detailsItem')
```

Update:

[Chandu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527185/chandu) is also right about the 'this' object being the window object within an href='javascript:...'.
You can also use the onclick='' attribute where the 'this' object is a reference to the actual anchor.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code `this` context is set to the `window` object when the editItem function is executed.

Instead bind the click event unobstrusively.

e.g:

```
<div class="detailsItem">
    <table style="width:100%;border: solid green 1px">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">
            <a href="#edit" class="edit-item">Edit</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $(".edit-item").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        editItem($(this).closest('.detailsItem')); //Changed the class selector to match what you have in HTML
    });
 });
</script>
```